# What is T in nn.Linear equation?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to understand the PyTorch's `nn.Linear`. I get that it applies a linear transformation to the input, but in the docs they specify the equation being used as `y= xA^T + b`.

This reminds my of `y = (x[1] * w[1]) + (x[2] * w[2]) + b`. Is that at all what's happening here?

Also, here is my current understanding of the variables in this equation, is this correct?

`x` = input
`A` = weight (I think)
`T` = Not sure
`b` = bias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `T` stands for the transpose operation. For reasons that aren't entirely clear, pytorch stores the transpose of the weight matrix for linear layers. You can find some discussion of this [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2159), but it seems to be a legacy thing.

```py
layer = nn.Linear(64, 128)
layer.weight.shape
> torch.Size([128, 64]) # we would expect (64, 128) but we get the transpose (128, 64)

x = torch.randn(8, 64) # random input

# nn.Linear computes `xA^T + b`
((x@layer.weight.T) + layer.bias == layer(x)).all()
> tensor(True)
```

Comment: Good explanation. I'll also call out that `@` is a matrix multiplication operator, so this could be written out as `(1.2921 * -0.3518) + (0.6608 * 0.5228) + -0.1950`, for example.